# Reboot server running XP via ssh

Tags: ssh, reboot

How can I reboot my server which is running XP via ssh? I think it may have partially crashed, but at any rate it isnt letting me connect via RDP.

Thanks for the help!

EDIT: I am using putty, and it doesnt seem to be prompting me for a username or password.

Is this a problem?

Comment: Are you running an SSH server on the machine? If not, you won't be able to connect that way.

Comment: I thought I was, but apparently I am not...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually, Shutdown.exe has a parameter that allows you to specify machine name.  You do not have to have an SSH server on the machine you want to reboot.

```
Shutdown /r /m \\WindowsXPServerName
```

Comment: But I can't even access the machine

Comment: What do you mean you can't access the machine?  Do you mean physically or over the network?  
If you don't even have network access I don't know how you'd be able to reboot the machine remotely.  
If you just don't have physical access, you can execute Shutdown from a remote machine and just specify the computer name or IP address of the XP Server you'd like to reboot.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, he needs shutdown -r if he wants to reboot the machine rather than just power it down.

Answer (score -1):

Well, if you have SSH access, try the shutdown command?

You want...

> Shutdown -r

... This is dependent on what SSH server you are using, but most I have seen should support this.

Comment: Gil's answer is correct; OP's asking for reboot, so use `-r` instead of `-s`

Comment: changed to r... I did that wrong :(